# Accessing an updated variable value from another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project with three different view controllers:

ViewController (this is where the user inputs values), LoadingViewController (loading screen), and AnswerViewController (where I want the result of an updated value in the first view controller to be loaded.)

Here's the code in ViewController:

```
var calculatedRatio: Double?

@IBOutlet weak var boysCountTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var girlsCountTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if boysCountTextField.text != "" && girlsCountTextField.text != "" {
        calculateRatio()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingAnswer", sender: self)
    }
}

func calculateRatio() {

    let boysCount = Double(boysCountTextField.text!)!
    let girlsCount = Double(girlsCountTextField.text!)!

    let currentRatio = boysCount / girlsCount

    calculatedRatio = currentRatio
    print(calculatedRatio)

}
```

As you can see, in this view controller I've created a variable at the top called `calculatedRatio` which is an optional double. And in the same view controller, once you press on a button, it runs a function on the bottom called `calculateRatio()` which updates the `calculatedRatio` value.

My question is, how am I able to access this variable's new value in a different view controller (AnswerViewController) that I am not directly segueing into?

I've already attempted to make an instance of ViewController within AnswerViewController, but the variable is copied with its initial value (which in this case is nil) instead of the new value given by the `calculateRatio()` function.

Comment: Have you tried using delegation?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show a loading screen that is its own view controller while processing a complex method. I'm assuming there a reason you want to throw a loading screen on the navigation stack instead of doing some type of modal overlay. I'm also assuming there is a reason the calculations MUST be done on the first View controller (as opposed to the loading screen) and there is no better way to abstract the calculations out elsewhere. Why don't you try NSNotifications? You can listen for the calculation to finish in the LoadingViewController and pass the updates value as an object.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loadingAnswer"]) {
        LoadingViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        destinationViewController. calculatedRatio = self. calculatedRatio
    }
}

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "loadingAnswer") {
        let vc:LoadingViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as LoadingViewController
           vc. calculatedRatio = self. calculatedRatio
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegation pattern of iOS application. Here I am trying to solve your problem. I made some change your Input ViewController Class to implement delegate of AnswerViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,AnswerVCProtocol {
  var calculatedRatio: Double?

  @IBOutlet weak var boysCountTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var girlsCountTextField: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if boysCountTextField.text != "" && girlsCountTextField.text != "" {
      calculateRatio()
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingAnswer", sender: self)
    }
  }

  func calculateRatio() {

    let boysCount = Double(boysCountTextField.text!)!
    let girlsCount = Double(girlsCountTextField.text!)!

    let currentRatio = boysCount / girlsCount

    calculatedRatio = currentRatio
    print(calculatedRatio)

  }

  // MARK: AnswerViewController Delegate

  func getUpdateRadio()-> Double?{
    return self.calculatedRatio
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Please check you identifier as you given in storyboard
    if segue.identifier == "loadingAnswer"{

      let ansVc = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerViewController

      ansVc.delegate = self

    }

  }


}
```

Here is the protocol

```
protocol AnswerVCProtocol{
  func getUpdateRadio()-> Double?
}
```

Now I guess your AnswerViewController something like this. Here I only show how can you access the variable through delegate.

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController {

  var delegate: AnswerVCProtocol?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    <#code#>
  }
  // To receive update value call this function when you needed
  // Receive Update Value from your Input ViewController
  func updateRadio(){
    if let _ = self.delegate{
     let updateRatio =  delegate?.getUpdateRadio()
    }

  }

}
```

**Overview**

1. Declare protocol. In this case `AnswerVCProtocol`.
2. Confirm the protocol in your input ViewController.